Flexmonster how to apply row/column freezing/pinning like excel
I would like to know whether is it possible to freeze/pin column
Is there option to do row pinning/freezing or column pinning/freezing and if so can freeze/pin particular column/row using flexmonster.
Please help needed
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flexmonster Column Pinning Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.flexmonster.com/2.8.16/flexmonster.css">
    <style>
        #pivot-container {
            height: 600px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.flexmonster.com/2.8.16/flexmonster.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pivot-container"></div>

    <script>
        const pivot = new Flexmonster({
            container: "#pivot-container",
            toolbar: true,
            height: "100%",
            report: {
                dataSource: {
                    data: [
                        { "Product": "Apple", "Region": "North", "Sales": 1500 },
                        { "Product": "Orange", "Region": "South", "Sales": 1200 },
                        { "Product": "Banana", "Region": "East", "Sales": 1300 },
                        { "Product": "Grapes", "Region": "West", "Sales": 1700 }
                    ]
                },
                slices: {
                    rows: [{
                        uniqueName: "Product"
                    }],
                    columns: [{
                        uniqueName: "Region"
                    }],
                    measures: [{
                        uniqueName: "Sales",
                        aggregation: "sum"
                    }]
                }
            },
          
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>



Literally the first hit in Google for your title: https://www.flexmonster.com/question/how-to-freeze-first-columns/
